# 3ware 9650se not recognizing SAS drives, what else should I check?

Tags: hardware-raid, sas, 3ware

The card works fine with SATA Raptors but can't see 2 different models of Cheetah. Drives are fine and have standard fw - visible with LSI 3081ER.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, 9650se is SATA controller and therefore it doesn't support SAS drives.

Comment: doh! I was actually wondering if that was the case, would be the only logical explanation. Thanks for your assistance!